# Mouse 'swipe' gestures for VMWare Fusion

Tags: windows, mac, vmware-fusion, gestures

Is there any way to enable the 'swipe' gestures available within Mac OS X inside Fusion?

I'm regularly trying to swipe around in my Windows guest machines until I realise I'm [not in Kansas any more](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032138/quotes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The Fusion mouse driver does not include this and even the current Boot-camp drivers doesn't support this in Windows. Until Apple or VMWare produce a driver that does support this functionality it will most likely not happen.

The Apple Boot-camp driver does however support right-click and 2 finger scroll.

Comment: I hope they get this added soon.

Comment: Has this changed with Fusion 9 or 10?